# PS3 controller not working

Tags: ps3, controllers

My original Sony controller won't even connect to the PS3 even after resetting several times, whether connected to the USB or not, what should I do? I have another controller which isn't Sony and when plugged into the USB the red lights flash for about a minute then go off but none of the buttons work, what does that mean? Its also been reset several times.... Help....

Answer (score 1):

You need to sync the controller with the PS3 before it'll work with your console.

To sync your controller, connect it to the console via the USB cable, the 4 lights on the top should flash. Now press the PS (i.e. Home) button (large round button in the middle of the controller, between Start, Select & the analog sticks). Only one light should flash now. You should now be able to disconnect the controller and use it normally.

If this doesn't work, it could be your controller or console are faulty.